# MatPlotLib coulored triangulars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have no idea how to plot the following. My data file contains the corner points of many triangulars in the following structure:

```
1 0
0 1
1 1

0.1 1
0.2 2
0.3 3
```

I want to draw them in one image and color the surface of each triangles differently. How do I do that?

Thanks for the help : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick look at [artist demo](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/artist_demo.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
triangle1 = mpatches.Polygon(np.array([[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]), fc="blue")
triangle2 = mpatches.Polygon(np.array([[-0.1,-1],[-2,-2],[-2,-1]]), fc="red")
ax.add_artist(triangle1)
ax.add_artist(triangle2)
ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-3, 3)
plt.show()
```

[image: triangle]

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you posted:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
import itertools

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

with open('data') as f:
    for points in zip(*[itertools.ifilter(lambda line: line.strip(),f)]*3):
        points=([tuple(map(float,p.strip().split())) for p in points])
        ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(points))
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image]